# Generate Dynamic Links in Django : Company and Employee

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am making a project in Django which is an Employee Management System.

I made the Company Home page where we have options to add a new Company, Delete Previous Company or Delete it.

Now I want when I click on that Company Name, it generates a dynamic link for that particular company name (which will have the same features of adding, deleting and editing the Employee)

Currently, I am stuck. Not able to generate Dynamic links for each Company which gives Employee details.

Here is my Models.py File

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignKey
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.

class companyModel(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    company_created = models.DateField(default=datetime.now,blank=False)

class employeeModel(models.Model):
    employee_company_name = models.ForeignKey(companyModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    employee_created = models.DateField(default=datetime.now,blank=False)
```

Forms.py File

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import widgets
from empman.models import companyModel,employeeModel

class companyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = companyModel
        fields = ['company_name','company_created']
        widgets = {
            'company_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control '}),
            'company_created':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
        }

class employeeForm(forms.ModelForm):    
    class Meta:
        model = employeeModel
        fields = ['employee_company_name','employee_name','employee_created']
```

Views.py File

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
from empman.forms import companyForm,employeeForm
from empman.models import companyModel,employeeModel
# Create your views here.
def companyShowView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = companyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = companyForm()
    
    comp = companyModel.objects.all()
    return render(request,'empman/companyshow.html',{'form':form,'comp':comp})

def editCompany(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uniqueid = companyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
        requestpost = companyForm(request.POST,instance=uniqueid)
        if requestpost.is_valid():
            requestpost.save()
            return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/')
    else:
        uniqueid = companyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
        requestpost = companyForm(instance=uniqueid)
    return render(request,'empman/companyupdate.html',{'form':requestpost})

def deleteCompany(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dele=companyModel.objects.get(pk=id)
        dele.delete()
        return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect('/')


# def viewEmployee(request,id):
#     print(id)
#     return render(request,'empman/employeeshow.html')

def viewEmployee(request,id):
    showemps = employeeModel.objects.all()
    return render(request,'empman/employeeshow.html')

def employeeShowView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        empform = employeeForm(request.POST)
        if empform.is_valid():
            empform.save()
            
    else:
        form = employeeForm()
    
    emp = employeeModel.objects.all()
    return render(request,'empman/employeeshow.html',{'empform':empform,'emp':emp})
```

urls.py File

```
# from mysite.empman.views import editCompany
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from empman import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.companyShowView,name='index'),
    path('delete/<int:id>',views.deleteCompany,name='deletecomp'),
    path('<int:id>/edit',views.editCompany,name='editcomp'),
    path('<int:id>/employee/',views.viewEmployee,name='showemp')
]
```

companyShow.html

```
{% extends 'empman/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p></p>
<center>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h4 class="alert alert-info">Add new Company</h4>
    <form class="form-control" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="ADD" id="add">
</form>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <p></p>
    <h4 class="alert alert-info">Here is the list of companies</h4>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <th class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Sr</th>
            <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Creation Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Operations</th>
        </tr> 
        </th> 
        <tbody>
          {% for comps in comp %}  
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">{{comps.id}}</th>
            <th scope="col"><a href="{% url 'showemp' comps.id %}">{{comps.company_name}}</a></th>
            <th scope="col">{{comps.company_created}}</th>
            <td>
                <!-- <a href="{% url 'showemp' comps.id %}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">View</a> -->
                <a href="{% url 'editcomp' comps.id %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Edit</a>
                <form action="{% url 'deletecomp' comps.id %}" method="POST" class="d-inline">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
                </form>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
</center>
{% endblock content %}
```

employeeShow.html

```
{% extends 'empman/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p></p>
<center>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <h4 class="alert alert-info">Add new Employee</h4>
    <form class="form-control" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{empform}}
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="ADD" id="add">
</form>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <p></p>
    <h4 class="alert alert-info">Employees for {{eachshowemps.employee_company_name.company_name}}</h4>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <th class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Employee Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Joining Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Operations</th>
        </tr> 
        </th> 
        <tbody>
          {% for eachshowemps in showemps %}  
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">{{eachshowemps.id}}</th>
            <th scope="col">{{eachshowemps.employee_name}}</th>
            <th scope="col">{{eachshowemps.employee_created}}</th>
            <td>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
</center>
{% endblock content %}
```

currently, The edit and delete on my Company works fine

[image]

Comment: Right Now when I click on the Company Name it gives me "employeeModel matching query does not exist." error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `viewEmployee` function is supposed to return the CompanyModel instance not the all queryset of employeeModel

```
def viewEmployee(request,id):
    company = companyModel.objects.get(id=id)
    employess = company.employeemodel_set.all() #employess of that company
    return render(request,'empman/employeeshow.html', {'company':company, 'showemps':employees})
```

Also consider using the meaningful names for your views too.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I did but still it throws error - employeeModel matching query does not exist." error

Comment: If I iterate over this 'company', can I fetch the employees data as well or just the company data. ?

Comment: You can't iterate over `company` since it's a single object. You can iterate over `employees` which will return the employees queryset of that company.

Comment: Thanks that worked, 

    company = companyModel.objects.get(id=id)
    employees = company.employeemodel_set.all() #employess of that company
    return render(request,'empman/employeeshow.html', {'company':company, 'showemps':employees})

Comment: Consider [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  as well if it works @AkshatSharma

Comment: thanks once again , also accepted it , could you please correct the employees spelling !

Comment: I think that inorder to give option to add Employee we need to use the company modal only